# The time that the server went down, Microsoft Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am looking for information when exactly my server has crashed. Where can I find it?

I know where the all logs are, but I can not find info about the downtime, I do not know where could it be.

Thanks for the answears!

Answer (score 1):

look in **System** in the event viewer.  Event ID 6008

"The previous system shutdown at 11:48:44 on ‎19/‎08/‎2011 was unexpected."

Comment: But in which log file it can be? I've looked it over and I have no idea. 

I know that I can looking for gaps in some logs and it give me time when the server was broken. And next question: which log file is the best way to reveal the gaps?

Comment: I told you which log

Comment: I have this event but only one and it was caused by me. Problem is that server sometimes is not working and I have to find out when exactely and maybe why.

Answer (score 0):

That can be misleading though. This reflects actually the time of the last heartbeat that was recognized by the event logging service. The crash might have occured later, since this event is logged after the reboot. 
The system saves periodically a "Alert Flag" in the registry and clears it in case of a regular reboot. If the Flag is empty at reboot, no special event is logged. If the flag is set, the time of this Setting is used as crash time. 
But beside that, the System log is of course the right place to look.